# Pause on anonymous function, when function is defined

Tags: javascript

I have this function in my js script.

```
//handle the deleting of the shoutlines
function delete_shoutline(shoutline_number)
{
    //the number of the shoutline we're deleting
    var shoutline = shoutline_number;

    $.post("shoutbox/delete_ban.php", {shoutline : shoutline_number},
    function(result)
    {
        //show the result, if any
        alert(result);

        //refresh the page
        window.location = window.location;
    });

}
//handle the banning of users
function ban_user(user_ban)
{
    //the name of the user we are banning
    var banned = user_ban;

    $.post("shoutbox/delete_ban.php", {banned : user_ban},
    function(result)
    {
        //show the result, if any
        alert(result);

        //refresh the page
        window.location = window.location;
    });

}
```

here are the calls

```
<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline(SOMEID);' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='javascript: ban_user(SOMEUSER);' title='Ban' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to ban this user?');\">o</a>
```

the function `delete_shoutline` works great, but when I click the ban link my console pauses and says `(anonymous function) members.php (2):1
Paused on exception 'ReferenceError'`

and Debugger says `Uncaught ReferenceError: SOMEUSER is not defined`

I am not the best with js so I really don't know what this means?
I am not really sure what this means because the function is defined in the js.

Comment: As the console is clearly telling you, you have an error in your function.  Use the debugger.

Comment: FYI: this line `var banned = user_ban;` is not doing anything and can be removed.

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded in your page?  Is `SOMEUSER` define as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the string.

```
<a href='javascript: ban_user(SOMEUSER);'  <-- no quotes around SOMEUSER, it thinks it is a variable.
```

Comment: Well thanks, because I did not know that, as I said I do not know much about javascript. I feel like an idiot because it was that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Is SOMEUSER supposed to be the username?  If so, quote it, e.g. `ban_user("SOMEUSER")`  Yo udon't need to quote on deleting some shoutline because SOMEID is likely an int, so no need to quote it.  But strings need to be quoted, or else it assumes it's a variable.